# Group columns in pandas dataframe and reduce amount

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Not too sure how to phrase this, but I can give a pretty clear example.

Given the following data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 0, 0], "b": [0, 1, 0], "c": [1, 0, 1], "d": [0, 0, 1], "e": [1, 0, 0]}
)
```

which looks as

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  0  1  0  1
1  0  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  1  0
```

I would like to convert it to

```py
df_r = pd.DataFrame({"up": [1, 1, 0], "down": [1, 0, 1], "neither": [1, 0, 0]})
```

which looks as

```
   up  down  neither
0   1     1        1
1   1     0        0
2   0     1        0
```

The solution should not depend on the shape of the above data - either the shape of the input or the output. It should be able to take a set of columns and, according to some logic, process them into a different dataframe where the meanings are represented without duplication.

Which columns are which are known already, its coding the logic which isn't clear.

Here's some pseudo code

```
upcols = ['a', 'b']
downcols = ['c','d']


if original_column in upcols
    new_column = up
elif original_column in downcols
    new_column = down
else
    new_column = neither

<remove duplicate columns>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `any(axis=1)` on columns specified in `upcols` and `downcols`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1, 0, 0], "b": [0, 1, 0], "c": [1, 0, 1], "d": [0, 0, 1], "e": [1, 0, 0]}
)

upcols = ['a', 'b']
downcols = ['c','d']

df['neither'] = df[[c for c in df.columns if c not in upcols and c not in downcols]].any(axis=1).astype(int)
df['up'] = df[upcols].any(axis=1).astype(int)
df['down'] = df[downcols].any(axis=1).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   a  b  c  d  e  neither  up  down
0  1  0  1  0  1        1   1     1
1  0  1  0  0  0        0   1     0
2  0  0  1  1  0        0   0     1
```

---

To get only `up`, `down`, `neither` then you can do additionally:

```
df = df[['up', 'down', 'neither']]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   up  down  neither
0   1     1        1
1   1     0        0
2   0     1        0
```